# Java max digit (java.lang.NumberFormatException)

Tags: java

I'm trying to write a block of code where I take in a number and find the greatest number within that number. (e.g. 12345 would be 5 and 791 would be 9). However, when I go to put in my scanner method in the main() I get an error `java.lang.NumberFormatException` and have no clue what to do.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Step2 {

    private static int greatestnum = 0;
    private static int length = 0;
    private static int step = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner r = new Scanner(args[0]);
        String s = r.next();
        int t = Integer.parseInt(s);
        System.out.println(maxDigit(t));    
    }               

    public static int maxDigit(int num){
        num = Math.abs(num);
        String stringint = String.valueOf(num);
        length = stringint.length();
        String[] ary = stringint.split("");
        while ( step < length){
        int currentnum = Integer.parseInt(ary[step]);
            if(currentnum >= greatestnum){
                greatestnum = currentnum;
            }
            step++;
        }
        return greatestnum;
    }

}
```

I really could use some help, I have to do the same thing recursively and don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
private static int greatestnum = '0';

public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner r = new Scanner(args[0]);
    String s = r.next().trim();
    char c[] = s.toCharArray();
    for ( int i = 0 ; i < c.length ; i++ ) {
        if ( c[i] > greatestnum ) {
            greatestnum = c[i];
        }
    }
    System.out.println(greatestnum-48);
}
```

**Explanation**:

- The string is a sequence of characters
- Every character has a code ('0', ..., '9' are stored in this order => '0' < '9' )
- If you want to get back the number, you need to remove 48 from that char code

Comment: This is super complicating simple logic by no means this is an wrong answer but its just too complicated. The OP is beginner you might want to add why is -48 and a brief description on ASCII values. and not just "If you want to get back the number, you need to remove 48 from that char code"

Answer (score 1):

Below you have code that gets input whatever this input is and checks only digits.

```
    Scanner r = new Scanner(args[0]);

    char max = '0';

    // for all tokens in input string
    while (r.hasNext()) {

        // next token (whatever it is)
        String token = r.next();

        // iterate thru all chars in this token
        for (int i = 0; i < token.length(); i++) {
            char c = token.charAt(i);
            if (Character.isDigit(c) && c > max) {
                max = c;
            }
        }
    }

    // print max found digit
    System.out.println(max);
```

Sample results:

```
input: 2348343
output: 8

input: a brown fox 145 jump 71 over
output: 7
```

Answer (score 0):

The Integer.parseInt throws NumberFormatException if it cannot convert a string into integer. In your case I would check the values of input that is s.

JavaDoc for [Integer.parseInt(String s)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt(java.lang.String))

Examples

```
Integer.parseInt(" 234"); ---> Throws NumberFormatException as it has space
Integer.parseInt(""); ---> Throws NumberFormatException as it is not parseable for an integer
Integer.parseInt(null); ---> Throws NumberFormatException and not npe
Integer.parseInt(" 234 ".trim()); ---> Doesnt throw NumberFormatException as it trims before trying to parse it.
```

I would try

```
int t = Integer.parseInt(s.trim());
```

This would clear your NumberFormatException.

As for the other part of your question it is a very poor effort.
Please read the java doc for split string. stringint.split(""); what are you splitting the string with ???

You should be using the modulo operator. that is %.
Usage 5%2 will return 1 that is the remainder

if you do something like this in a loop

```
public static int maxDigit(int num){
    int maxDigit=0;
    while(num>0) {
       if(maxDigit<num%10){
           maxDigit=num%10;
       }
       num/=10;
    }
    return maxDigit;
}
```

The maxDigit will have what you need. This is a looping approach try recursive your self show the effort I would be wiling to help you if i see the effort.

Comment: What is the value of s? can you do System.out.println("s is : "+s);

Comment: so, I'm running this on eclipse and I go under the run-as properties for this class and put in the argument under the argument section "12345" so my scanner will take that value and put it in s and then convert s to the integer 12345 stored in t and then take t and plug it into maxDigit and print it out.

Comment: after using trim you still get NumberFormatException ?

Comment: yes, if it helps the lone error appears to be on the following line of code now                                                                 int currentnum = Interger.parseInt(ary[step])